# Pl-sql for date

Tags: sql, date, plsql

I need to write Pl/SQL code that will count of rows print from 1/April/2018(00:00-23:59) to 30/April/18(00:00-23:59)

Comment: PL/SQL? Print? So you are on an Oracle database and want to write a stored procedure that writes output to the console?

Answer (score 2):

```
select count(*)
from your_table
where date_column between to_date('01.04.2018 00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi')
                      and to_date('30.04.2018 23:59', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi');
```

**[EDIT: counting per every day]**

```
select trunc(date_column) date_value,
       count(*)
from your_table
where date_column between to_date('01.04.2018 00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi')
                      and to_date('30.04.2018 23:59', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi')
group by trunc(date_column)
order by 1;
```

Comment: I need a loop that will increment automatically days

Comment: What does that mean? Do you need to perform count for each day? If so, I edited my message, have a look.

Comment: No! I need 1 April(00:00-23:59)

Comment: Then i need 2 April(00:00-23:59). So it will continue 30 April

Comment: If you apply the `TRUNC` function to a date value, you'll get all rows that belong to that date, as you say it - *from 00:00 to 23:59*, so I'd say that my second query *should* do what you're asking. Did you try it?

Comment: Kudos for trying, @Littlefoot. You're a far more patient person than I. Rauf, if this isn't doing what you need it to, try [fixing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It's extremely unclear.

Comment: You know how it goes, @Joe - there are 10 types of people - those who are patient, and those who are not :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply printing rows in row can be achieved by level function. Hope below snippet helps.

```
SELECT to_date('04/01/2018','MM/DD/YYYY') + (level -1)
FROM dual
  CONNECT BY level <= TO_CHAR(last_day(to_date('04/01/2018','MM/DD/YYYY')),'fmDD');
```